# Sitecore - Web Forms for Marketers - Send Mail Editor: No option was shown on the Insert Field drop down list

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I was blocked when implementing the send mail feature by Web Forms for Marketers.

I have checked the user guide before and it said I could use the 'Insert Field dropdownlist' to reference the form values on the send mail editor dialog.

My questions:
1. I cannot see any options on the insert field dropdownlist. Should I do any configuration to reach that?
2. I can use [EMail] on the To/CC/BCC/Subject fields to reference the value from form field, but I cannot do the same thing on the content field. How can I reference the form values on the content field?

Thanks

Comment: Three installations are available on the sitecore site. They are rev_110621, rev_110324, and rev_101221. The dropdownlist work right on rev_110621 & rev_101221, but not works on the rev_110324. Does somebody meet the same problem before?

Answer (score 2):

We experienced the same issue on our version of **SC 6.4.1 with the WFM module 2.2.0_rev_101207** and I was able to get the drop-down list to populate correctly by setting the display name of the Insert Field toolbar button in the core DB to: "Insert Field".

You can find the relevant HTML Editor Profile by flipping over to the Core DB and browsing to: */sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Mail/Toolbar 1/Insert Field*

Under Appearance, set the "Display Name" field value to "Insert Field" (don't use the Ribbon... do it directly on the field), flip back to master, and see if it now populates.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be able to select any user fields from the dropdown under the subject field. Just move the cursor to the content field and select a value from the dropdown list should be enough usually. Also if you are not able to select any value please make sure the website is in your safe website list if you. Do this by going to internet options and adding the site to the trusted websites. I have had the problem of not being able to select a user field from the list before and solved it by adding the website to the safe sites list.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't documented anywhere to my knowledge, but may have luck with the following format:

```
[<label id="{Sitecore Field ID}">Field Name</label>]
```

Here is an example usage:

```
<p>Form data:</p>
<ul>
    <li>First Name:  [<label id="{3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301}">First Name</label>]</li>
    <li>Last Name:  [<label id="{BAC81E84-E304-4DBE-BBF6-F6747434FA20}">Last Name</label>]</li>
    <li>Email:  [<label id="{8FA74988-2B79-40F2-B6F1-DAD4F0B27CAC}">Email</label>]</li>
</ul>
```