# Insert field dropdown list empty in Web forms for marketers in Send email -actions dialog

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

This question has been asked before and no definite answer has been given.

I'm working with Sitecore 6.4 and Web forms for marketers 2.2.0 rev 110303. I have created a form with 'Send email' -action. When I open the action in editor, I cannot see any fields in the 'Insert field' -drop-down list. I have created a few test fields on the form.

In this post it was suggested, that the problem was in rev_110324 of the Web forms for marketers: [Sitecore - Web Forms for Marketers - Send Mail Editor: No option was shown on the Insert Field drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591464/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-send-mail-editor-no-option-was-shown-on-th)

I have tried adding the site to IE's trusted sites list, but that did not help. I would like to know if this is some kind of a configuration issue or a bug in rev 110303.

Thank you for your replies in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posted a solution where setting the Display Name of HTML Editor Button in Core fired up the dropdown list (finally) that worked for us.

[Sitecore - Web Forms for Marketers - Send Mail Editor: No option was shown on the Insert Field drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591464/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-send-mail-editor-no-option-was-shown-on-th)

Hope it works for you too.

~Cheers

Comment: **Thank you**, the solution you suggested worked for me as well! The insert field dropdown was populated right away after implementing your fix.